# (q/kdb+) Create a table with string column

Tags: kdb

I can create the following table in kdb using

```
([]idx:0,1,2;str:"a","b","c")

idx str
0   a
1   b
2   c
```

but I cant do for instance

```
([]idx:0,1,2;str:"aa","bb","cc")
```

I would like to get

```
idx str
0   aa
1   bb
2   cc
```

What am I doing wrong when creating this string column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use braces and semi-colons rather than commas to separate list items:

```
q)([]idx:(0;1;2);str:("aa";"bb";"cc"))
idx str
--------
0   "aa"
1   "bb"
2   "cc"
```